# java array exact length

Tags: java

I set an array of integer like below

```
int[] a = new int[11111];
 //if I set
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;
a[3] = 4;
```

I want a method such that it gives me 
4 but 11111.
Is there any method which I can use?

Comment: Have you considered using an `ArrayList` instead?

Comment: Is this homework? If it isn't, use an ArrayList.

Comment: The question is: is 0 a valid value? It is an integer and as such `new int[11111]` would result in an array of 11111 valid integers.

Comment: I don't get these "Is this homework?" comments all over the place. Why does that matter? Why he should not use an ArrayList if it is homework...? No offense.

Comment: @Tim If this is homework there might be constraints like "you have to use that int array". Besides that, we'd like to know if it's homework when someone asks for a solution and not just for help in finding problems within his own work.

Comment: What did you mean by `it gives me 4 but 11111`? did you mean get `int[4]` from `int[1111]`?

Comment: Eng.Fouad exactly. The question is meaningless in its present form.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad - I read that part as the questioner trying `a.length`, hoping it would return 4, but seeing it actually return 11111.  Though I agree it's not very well worded, hence the sarcastic start to my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look into using an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
myList.add(1);
myList.add(2);
myList.add(3);

System.out.println("Size:"+myList.size());
```

Comment: unless he is realy wants an array for some mistery reason with this exact size :)

Comment: @Eamorr you should use generics in the `new` expression as well.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the following method will do what you asked for:

```
public int m() {
    return 4;
}
```

On the assumption that you want a method that takes an array, and returns the greatest index that has been populated - you're right that the `a.length` only tells you the size of the array, i.e. the number of cells allocated.

This is going to be harder than you might expect, especially with an `int` array.  Those unassigned cells are initialised to a value of `0`.  If you might actually use zero values in your array, then there is absolutely no way to tell whether the value in a cell is the "default" zero or one that you've set yourself.

If the array can't have zero values in it, then you'd need to loop over its entire length, checking for the highest index with a corresponding non-zero value; something like this:

```
public int dynamicLength(int[] a) {
   int max = -1;
   for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       if (a[i] != 0) max = i;
   }
   return max;
}
```

Even then this might not be ideal, since arrays can be sparsely populated.  Do you want the count of assigned indices, or the index of the highest assigned index?

---

The short answer is almost certainly "use an `ArrayList`".

Comment: +0.5 for the humor, and +0.5 for the method :D

Answer (score 1):

You should use an ArrayList if the size of the array is changing. There is little performance difference.

See [here for how to use one.](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/collections/lists/arraylist.html) See [here for the API also.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

I understand that you only want the assigned elements to be counted but it would be safer at runtime and simpler to use an ArrayList. The ArrayList class just wraps a Java array and handles the changing size for you. You can get the size by calling the `size()` method on the ArrayList.

See this example using a for-each loop if you want to iterate over the elements:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1); //size is 1
list.add(2); //size is 2
list.add(3); //size is 3
list.add(4); //size is 4

for(Integer n : list)
    System.out.println(n);
```

An ArrayList uses an iterator and the for-each loop uses it to iterate over the ArrayList. Makes life much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

`int[] a = new int[11111]`

It creates an array with `11111` elements and as it is `int` it will assign it to default value that is `0` so you have array with all values set.

You should move to `List`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, using a List is probably the right answer. However, in the interest of solving the original problem, you could try this instead:

```
Integer[] foo = new Integer[11111];
foo[0] = new Integer(1);
foo[1] = new Integer(2);
foo[2] = new Integer(3);
foo[3] = new Integer(4);
```

and create a method that counts non-null values:

```
public static int countItems(Integer[] array) {
  int count = 0;

  for (Integer i : array) {
    if (i != null) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

Of course, this will be a pain to manage as you would need to nullify any items no longer needed. It also raises the question of whether you would accept "holes" in your array, e.g. null values amongst non-null values. My example counting function above would accept such holes.

So, yes. Use a List.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method which calculates the non-0 elements of the array using a `for`/`while` loop.